# External JS file callback using component class property in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

I'm using an external js file in my angular component like so:

```
declare var external: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'payment-form',
  templateUrl: './payment-form.component.html'
})
export class PaymentFormComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  testVar = 'test';

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    external.init({
      'error-callback': this.onExternalError,
      'debug': true
    });
  }
  onExternalError(errors) {
    console.error(errors);
    console.log(this.testVar);
    this.showErrors();
  }

  showErrors() {
    console.log('errors');
  }
}
```

The external js file has a function called `init()` which I call in `ngAfterViewInit()`. This function takes a callback function for errors, and I give it the function `onExternalError`. It does run the correct function on error and I can see the `console.log(errors)`. The problem is coming in the next line when I try to use the `testVar` from my component's properties. It cannot access it and cannot find it as it is probably using the wrong instance where testVar does not exist.

The `this.showErrors` also won't work and I get the error `showErrors() is not a function`. Any ideas on how I can fix this or is it impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by using the `() => {}` instead of function callback and using `_this = this`:

```
declare var external: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'payment-form',
  templateUrl: './payment-form.component.html'
})
export class PaymentFormComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  testVar = 'test';
  external = external;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const _this = this;
    this.external.init({
      'error-callback': (errors) => {
        console.error(errors);
        console.log(_this.testVar);
        _this.showErrors();
      },
      'debug': true
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the current context and use it to call your variable:

```
that = this;
onExternalError(errors) {
    console.error(errors);
    console.log(that.testVar);
    this.showErrors();
  }
```

Comment: cannot work, how can I access `that` from inside that function?

Comment: @Gabb1995 it can be called like this in your function `let e =  that.testVar;`. Are you sure that your parameter of method `onExternalError(errors)` are initialized `errors`? I am asking because I haven't seen any declaration of variable. What I see is `declare var external: any;`.